# How to include all monitors in Gnome 3 workspace thumbnails

Tags: gnome, multiple-monitors, workspaces

I have a multi-monitor (two) setup and I'd like to be able to see all the windows I have open when I switch between workspaces. At the moment I end up overlooking that I already have a window open somewhere because the thumbnails only include the windows from the primary monitor.

I've already used the Tweaks tool to configure the workspaces to span displays, so I *do* have separate windows on each workspace, it's just that they aren't easily shown.

I've had a look on https://extensions.gnome.org/ and I don't see any extensions there which would do this.

In case it matters I'm also using the Dash to Panel and Workspace Matrix extensions (so it's actually the thumbnails in Workspace Matrix I care about, though I'm assuming that it's Gnome itself which is generating the thumbnails).

Comment: did you find a solution? i am seeking to get an overview of activities/workspaces on all monitors/displays

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the "Multi Monitors Add-On" Gnome Shell Extension by spin83:

[Multi Monitors Add-On by spin83](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/921/multi-monitors-add-on/)

This duplicates the desktop thumbnails that are on the primary monitor on a second (and presumably third) display.

This allows you to see thumbnails on additional monitors but also drag thumbnails from desktop to desktop to re-arrange things on that additional monitor.  It's a wonderful extension.

IF you are reading this around December 2020, do get [version 22.1 or later via github](https://github.com/spin83/multi-monitors-add-on/commit/f8343948ab835081f3be6987730decf592418e27) which fixes a bug that may cause recent versions of Gnome (like 3.38) to crash.

The author hasn't made a release of this version or posted it to extensions.gnome.org yet, but in time I expect they'll do so.